# Using Toggle repeatedly

Tags: jquery

I'm using toggle on each div section to show an image. It works fine but now the code is repeating. How can I make this DRY?

```
// Show hide Maps
$( ".secblue" ).click(function() {
  $( "#mgmap" ).toggle( "slow" );
});

// Show hide Maps
$( ".secgreen" ).click(function() {
  $( "#glmap" ).toggle( "slow" );
});

// Show hide Maps
$( ".secpurple" ).click(function() {
  $( "#ufmap" ).toggle( "slow" );
});

// Show hide Maps
 $( ".secorange" ).click(function() {
  $( "#llmap" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `data-target` attribute on each button (or anchor or div or whatever the element you are clicking on is):

```
<button class="secblue" data-target="mgmap">...</button>
<button class="secgreen" data-target="glmap">...</button>
...
```

and then just subscribe to the click event of all elements that have this `data-target` attribute, grab the corresponding target element and toggle it:

```
$('button[data-target]').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('#' + target).toggle('slow');
});
```